# How do I retrieve a hyperref TextField's value for later use?

Tags: email, textfield

I would like to retrieve a hyperref TextField's value for later use in an email submit.  As an example:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newdimen\longline

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % override default in hyperref
\def\lbl#1{\hbox to 4cm{#1\dotfill\strut}}%
\def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2]{\null}}\kern2pt\hrule}}

\def\q#1{\hbox to \hsize{\labelline{#1}{\longline}}\vskip1.4ex}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{12pt}%
\longline=0.95\textwidth\advance\longline-6em
\newcommand{\hgt}{17\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\nameRUID}{
    \TextField[name = Name,
        width = 7cm,
        borderwidth = 0,
        bordersep = 1pt,
        backgroundcolor = {.85 .85 .85}]
        {Name}
        \hskip1ex
    %%
    \TextField[name = RUID,
        width = 2.5cm,
        borderwidth = 0,
        bordersep = 4pt,
        backgroundcolor = {.85 .85 .85}]
        {RUID}
        \vskip1ex
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{6\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{\makebox[3.5em][l]{#1:}%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}}

\begin{Form}[action = mailto:forms <walt@dataanalyticscorp.com>?subject = Midterm Exam for this.getField('Name').value, method = get ]

    \nameRUID

    \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{
            \mypar
            \begin{boxedminipage}{6in}
                \begin{center}
                    {\LARGE \textbf{Click this Button to Submit Your Exam}}
                    \par\bigskip
                    {\Large Rename this pdf file to your Last Name and RUID BEFORE submitting.  Example: Smith\_1234.pdf}
                    \par\bigskip
                    \Submit[export=pdf]{{\large \textbf{Submit}}}
                    \par\bigskip
                \end{center}    
            \end{boxedminipage}
        }
\end{Form}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I want the Name entry from the \nameRUID command to be used in the email submit.  But I cannot figure out how to make this work.  Any advice?

Thanks,

Walt

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with javascript but here is an idea found [here](https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/sending-email-with-pdf-form-data-file-and-customize-email-subject/). What we need is to create a `\PushButton` with the option `onclick`.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newdimen\longline

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % override default in hyperref
\def\lbl#1{\hbox to 4cm{#1\dotfill\strut}}%
\def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2]{\null}}\kern2pt\hrule}}

\def\q#1{\hbox to \hsize{\labelline{#1}{\longline}}\vskip1.4ex}
\def\DefaultWidthofChoiceMenu{12pt}%
\longline=0.95\textwidth\advance\longline-6em
\newcommand{\hgt}{17\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\nameRUID}{
    \TextField[name = Name,
        width = 7cm,
        borderwidth = 0,
        bordersep = 1pt,
        backgroundcolor = {.85 .85 .85}]
        {Name}
        \hskip1ex
    %%
    \TextField[name = RUID,
        width = 2.5cm,
        borderwidth = 0,
        bordersep = 4pt,
        backgroundcolor = {.85 .85 .85}]
        {RUID}
        \vskip1ex
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{6\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{\makebox[3.5em][l]{#1:}%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}}

\begin{Form}

    \nameRUID

    \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{%
            \begin{minipage}{6in}
                \begin{center}
                    {\LARGE \textbf{Click this Button to Submit Your Exam}}
                    \par\bigskip
                    {\Large Rename this pdf file to your Last Name and RUID BEFORE submitting.  Example: Smith\_1234.pdf}
                    \par\bigskip
                   % \Submit{{\large \textbf{Submit}}}
                   \PushButton[
                        onclick={var TheSubject = "Midterm Exam for " + this.getField("Name").value; 
                        var mymailto = "mailto:forms <walt@dataanalyticscorp.com>?subject=" + TheSubject; 
                        this.submitForm({cURL: mymailto, cSubmitAs: "PDF" });}]{{\large \textbf{Submit}}}
                    \par\bigskip
                \end{center}    
            \end{minipage}}
\end{Form}

\newpage

\end{document}
```